# Full-page cache breaks store switcher

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, store-switcher

FPC is activated on the site. When I switch the store view on the Home page the Category page changes the language but the switcher remains unchanged.

The store code is added to the cookie correctly.
If you go to the Login page, the switcher changes its status, but when you go back to the Homepage, the status changes to incorrect

How do I resolve this bug?

---

I really need help with this.
Magento 2.3.2
It is possible to buy modules if required

Comment: your magento version is quite old. have you tried updating it and see if the bug is still there?

Comment: @PhilippSander This will be critical for the project.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone can help you with the information you provided. do you have the setting "use storecode in url" enabled? this can cause issues.

Comment: @PhilippSander This solves the problem, but on other projects, it works without the included config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed the issue? Could you please share the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t remember exactly how I had to correct the apache settings